# I am unable to create a new file in Android Studio

Tags: android, flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies, dart-pub

I have installed all dependencies and all the SDKs, but whenever I am opening a new Flutter project, only my reaadme.Md file is opening and main.dart file is not opening.

Also, when I click on project title my dart file gets excluded. How can I resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

Try following steps, this issue will be resolved.

1. Create a new folder in whenever location, name it like "X".
2. Go to "X" folder location, open it and in same folder open command
   prompt.
3. Type 'flutter create PROJECT_NAME'.
4. Go to Android Studio and import that folder/project.

Remember to have any IDE like Android Studio or Visual Code present in your PC/Laptop.

Answer (score 0):

for new file : go to project -> select the place where you want to put the file -> right click on the parent -> click new and select the type of file.

for new project : go to file (up left) - new -> new project